# Find two different combinations of (1,3), (2,7) and (1,5) that produce b=(0,1)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve the question:
Find two different combinations of u, v and w that produce b:

$u=\pmatrix{1\\3},$ $v=\pmatrix{2\\7},$ $w=\pmatrix{1\\5}$ and $b=\pmatrix{0\\1}$

My answers are:
$-2u+v$ and $u-v+w$

This is a question from the book "Introduction to Linear Algebra - Strang" and the solution to the problem has the following answers:
$-2u+v$ and $\frac{1}{2}w-\frac{1}{2}v$

I do not understand how $\frac{1}{2}w-\frac{1}{2}v$ can be a solution.

Comment: It should be $\frac 12 w - \frac 12 u$.

Comment: You are correct:$$\frac{1}{2}w-\frac{1}{2}v=\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\5/2\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}2/2\\7/2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1/2\\-1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that!